# Pass Authenticated Session In Another Request in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication, abcpdf

I am using ABCPDF.net to render my HTML to PDF pages, but I want to protect these using the current authenticated session.  However, the request to get the HTML to render the PDF doesnt carry over the session, but creates a new one.  I am using ASP.NET Membership, and passwigin the session ID and creating a cookie on the ASP.NET request.

```
    var sessionId = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Url)["sid"];

    if(sessionId != null)
    {
        doc.HtmlOptions.HttpAdditionalHeaders = string.Format("Cookie: 
                                    ASP.NET_SessionId={0}", sessionId);
    }
```

I read this in ABCPDF.net documentation and am doing just that, but the request always uses a different session.

[httpadditionalheaders](http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdf8net/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/httpadditionalheaders.htm)

Do I need to pass something else, or can I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by sending the auth cookie in the URL, and updating the cookie.

**Url To Call**

```
Url.ActionAbsolute(MVC.Events.Pools(eventId).AddRouteValue(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value)
```

**Global.asax**

```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            try
            {
                string auth_cookie_name = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

                if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
                {
                    UpdateCookie(auth_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]);
                }
                else if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName] != null)
                {
                    UpdateCookie(auth_cookie_name, HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]);
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        void UpdateCookie(string cookieName, string cookieValue)
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get(cookieName);
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                cookie = new HttpCookie(cookieName);
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(cookie);
            }
            cookie.Value = cookieValue;
            HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Set(cookie);

    }
```